# Who done it sp_blitz

Tags: sp-blitz

is there a way to add Session ID and timestamp to your first responders scripts? In particular the sp_BlitzLock. I am trying to find out when and by who some adhoc scripts are run that cause blocking on old SQL Server versions (2008R2/ 2012) .

Comment: It's a plain old stored procedure, so you can edit it at any time.

Comment: Create a PR if you have the code https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/pulls or you can file an issue "Enhancement" if you need that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First, sp_BlitzLock only helps you analyze deadlocks, not blocking.

Second, it won't run on 2008R2 -- it's 2012+ only. The deadlock XML definitions are sufficiently different to make supporting both unwieldy.

Third, it already includes the timestamp of the deadlock event, along with other identifying information. I don't think spid would be helpful.

[image: NUTS]